# Можно ли импортировать файл без импорта всего дерева?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import

Допустим есть 2 файла:

main.py
parsers.py

Файл main содержит точку входа и должен показать доступные парсеры.
Можно ли импортировать содержимое парсера не запуская импорты сделанные внутри файла parsers?
Main лишь собирает информацию и никогда не будет вызывать эти парсеры.

Answer (score 2):

Допустим можно изменить код `parsers.py` так:

```py
if __name__ == '__main__':
    import ...
# ваш код
```

---

UPD:

`main.py`

```
import parser
```

`parser.py`

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    import test
```

`test.py`

```
if __name__ != '__main__':
    print('imported')
```

Comment: Импорты внутри того файла/модуля что мы тут импортируем все равно будут выполнены.

Comment: @ИванКакуркин не будут. добавил описание

Comment: будут, т.к. дописанный вами вариант бесполезен для меня, другой файл импортирует парсеры и использует их. В файле парсеров есть импорты в самом начале файла, и они будут выполнены при простом импорте файла парсеров, а я ищу способ не простого импорта.

Answer (score 1):

Обычный пример
parser.py

```
import typing as t

A = 123
B = 888
```

main.py

```
from parser import *

print(dir())  
# Output: ['A', 'B', '__annotations__', '__builtins__', '__cached__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', '__spec__', 't']
```

Как видно из примера - импортируется все включая импортируемые библиотеки.

Добавление `__all__`. тут вы перечисляете все публичные объекты модуля которые должны быть открыты для импорта.

parser.py

```
import typing as t
__all__ = ['A']
A = 123
B = 888
```

main.py

```
from parser import *

print(dir())  
# Output: ['A', '__annotations__', '__builtins__', '__cached__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', '__spec__']
```

Как видно, импортировалась только переменная "A" которая добавлена в `__all__` .

Замечу, что такое можно проделывать не только с модулями, но и с пакетами в `__init__.py`.

Comment: Импортировалась только переменная A, но при этом импорт внутри модуля все равно выполнился ("запустился").

Comment: Согласен с комментарием выше, да и в "Допустим" 2 файла, а у меня их больше 50 (это вебсайт)

Comment: *>Добавление `__all__`. тут вы перечисляете все публичные объекты модуля которые должны быть открыты для импорта.* - неверно. Это лишь определяет то, что импортируется с использованием синтаксиса `from package import *`. Но это не запрещает сделать `from parser import B`, хоть и статические анализаторы кода будут возмущаться на это.